# Please tell me how to repeat this process in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Clicking 5 times on the light switch makes a chicken come out and an alert pop ups, after clicking the 5th time, the counter just keeps on adding and it doesnt restart. You probably already know my question, how do i make it restart the process each 5th click? I just want it do the same thing every 5 clicks...

This is the code below and here is the website for reference..www.deko.live
Help would be appreciated very much.

```
var flip = false;
var counter = 0;
function flipSwitch() {
    var themeColor = "#EEE8AA";
    var bright = "brightness(100%)";
    var lightS = "rotate(0deg)";
    var word = "PALI";
    var wordColor = "black"
    if (flip) {
        themeColor = "#EEE8AA";
        bright = "brightness(100%)";
        lightS = "rotate(0deg)";
        word = "ON";
        wordColor = "black";
        flip = false;
        counter++;
     } else {
        themeColor = "dimGray";
        bright = "brightness(50%)";
        lightS = "rotate(180deg)";
        word = "OFF";
        wordColor = "white";
        flip = true;
        counter++;
    }
    document.getElementById("theme").style.backgroundColor = themeColor;
    document.getElementById("roger").style.filter = bright;
    document.getElementById("lightSImg").style.transform = lightS;
    document.getElementById("lightSImg").style.filter = bright;
    document.getElementById("LifeOrDeath").innerHTML = word;
    document.getElementById("LifeOrDeath").style.color = wordColor;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
    surprise();
}

function surprise() {

     if (counter === 5) {
        document.getElementById("roger").src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/0/00/Roger_the_chick.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201044139"
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Surprise!"
        alert("WHOAA!!")
        }
}
```

Comment: you need to reset the counter after switching off so it will start the counter again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the value of counter never resets.

One of the solution is

```
function surprise() {

     if (counter === 5) {
        counter = 0;  // add this line
        document.getElementById("roger").src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/0/00/Roger_the_chick.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201044139"
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Surprise!"
        alert("WHOAA!!")
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may also try

```
function surprise() {

     if (counter % 5 === 0) {
        document.getElementById("roger").src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/0/00/Roger_the_chick.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201044139"
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Surprise!"
        alert("WHOAA!!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no sentence which resets the counter.

maybe you need another if condition to reset the counter to 0 when it hits 5

Answer (score 0):

just put statement to reset counter and remove effects try the snippet

```js
var flip = false;
var counter = 0;
function flipSwitch() {
    var themeColor = "#EEE8AA";
    var bright = "brightness(100%)";
    var lightS = "rotate(0deg)";
    var word = "PALI";
    var wordColor = "black"
    if (flip) {
        themeColor = "#EEE8AA";
        bright = "brightness(100%)";
        lightS = "rotate(0deg)";
        word = "ON";
        wordColor = "black";
        flip = false;
        counter++;
     } else {
        themeColor = "dimGray";
        bright = "brightness(50%)";
        lightS = "rotate(180deg)";
        word = "OFF";
        wordColor = "white";
        flip = true;
        counter++;
    }
    document.getElementById("theme").style.backgroundColor = themeColor;
    document.getElementById("roger").style.filter = bright;
    document.getElementById("lightSImg").style.transform = lightS;
    document.getElementById("lightSImg").style.filter = bright;
    document.getElementById("LifeOrDeath").innerHTML = word;
    document.getElementById("LifeOrDeath").style.color = wordColor;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
    surprise();
}

function surprise() {


     if (counter === 5) {
        document.getElementById("roger").src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/0/00/Roger_the_chick.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201044139";
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Surprise!";
        alert("WHOAA!!");
        counter = '0';
        } else {
        document.getElementById('roger').src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVL3aKJXXOdfviO2sx5h_lfDwpUsUs75BIcdWoFt72V_o6Au0&s";
     }
function surprise() {

     if (counter % 5 === 0) {
        document.getElementById("roger").src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/0/00/Roger_the_chick.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201044139"
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Surprise!"
        alert("WHOAA!!")
    }
}

}
```

```css
#LifeOrDeath {
font-size:1rem;
}
#theme {
position:relative;
width:50%;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}

#roger {
position:relative;
height:40vh;
}
#lightSImg {
position:relative;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="theme">
    <h1 id="LifeOrDeath">Flip tHE LIGHT Switch </h1>
    <img id="roger" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVL3aKJXXOdfviO2sx5h_lfDwpUsUs75BIcdWoFt72V_o6Au0&s">
    <p id="counter">0</p>
    <img onclick="flipSwitch()" id="lightSImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCUJZ.jpg">
    <script src="TEST.JS"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply rest your counter variable after every 5 clicks.

***Working code***

```
var flip = false;
var counter = 0;
function flipSwitch() {
    var themeColor = "#EEE8AA";
    var bright = "brightness(100%)";
    var lightS = "rotate(0deg)";
    var word = "PALI";
    var wordColor = "black"
    if (flip) {
        themeColor = "#EEE8AA";
        bright = "brightness(100%)";
        lightS = "rotate(0deg)";
        word = "ON";
        wordColor = "black";
        flip = false;
        counter++;
     } else {
        themeColor = "dimGray";
        bright = "brightness(50%)";
        lightS = "rotate(180deg)";
        word = "OFF";
        wordColor = "white";
        flip = true;
        counter++;
    }
    document.getElementById("theme").style.backgroundColor = themeColor;
    document.getElementById("roger").style.filter = bright;
    document.getElementById("lightSImg").style.transform = lightS;
    document.getElementById("lightSImg").style.filter = bright;
    document.getElementById("LifeOrDeath").innerHTML = word;
    document.getElementById("LifeOrDeath").style.color = wordColor;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
    surprise();
}

function surprise() {

     if (counter === 5) {
        document.getElementById("roger").src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/0/00/Roger_the_chick.png/revision/latest?cb=20141201044139"
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Surprise!"
        alert("WHOAA!!")
        counter = 0; // Add this line
     }
}
```